# Simpler way to activate a component when data available AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, components

I have "components" (I'm using Angular 1.4.4 so they are directives) that need some data when bootstrapping, passed as an attribute. But sometimes that data is being loaded async.

I actually come to this:

```
module('whatever').directive('my-directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            valueBinded: '=valueBinded' 
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
          // binded value is accesible through scope
          var unbindActivateListener = $scope.$watch("valueBinded", function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (typeof newVal !== "undefined") {  // Check if valueBinded contains valid information
                    unbindActivateListener();
                    activate();
                }
            });

          function activate() {
            console.log($scope.valueBinded) // Logs 
          }

        }],
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="valueBinded"/>';
    };
});
```

```

Which constantly watches for value and once is not `undefined` it calls to `activate()` method.

Obviously, adding this on each component is not nice. Is there a way where this can be refactored? Or preventing loading a directive until data is retrieved?

Comment: Have you tried using a `component` instead of a `directive`? You could watch for changes in your one way bindings through `this.$onChanges` method of your component controller. More on the subject [in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.4.4 so component is not available. I'm adding it to the question.